# What do ellipsis mean in a SQL statement made through Dapper?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, dapper

I am reading through some code and came across the following lines:

```cs
await connection.ExecuteAsync("CREATE TABLE #TempTable (Col1 NVARCHAR(20), Col2 NVARCHAR(20))", transaction: transaction);
await connection.BulkInsertAsync("INSERT INTO #TempTable VALUES (@Col1,@Col2) ...", transaction: transaction);
```

If I try pasting the above statements into SSMS, I get a message `Incorrect syntax near '.'.`; however, it seems to work just fine here. I'd like to figure out what this is doing to know whether or not it's safe to remove.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. `BulkInsertAsync` actually comes from the `Faithlife.Utility.Dapper` library, not directly from Dapper. According to [their documentation](https://github.com/Faithlife/DapperUtility/blob/master/docs/BulkInsert.md#solution), you must include an ellipsis after an insert statement's values.